# Transiting at Dubai International Airport

Tags: indian-citizens, uae, visas-on-arrival, emirates

I am an Indian citizen with EU residence permit (Blue Card) from Germany, traveling from Germany to India via Dubai (DXB). I deliberately took a halt of 20 hours to explore the city for a day before heading to my destination in India, and according to various sources, I am eligible for Visa on Arrival (48 hours, 96 hours and 14 days).

I do however have a few questions:

1) My flight arrives DXB at 6:30 AM in the morning and my connecting flight to India is at 2:30 AM the next morning. Do I need to show any proof of accommodation?

2) If the answer to the above question is yes, can I skip hotel reservation and choose to show proof of residence of my friend and her husband, who are Indians but are residents of the UAE?

3) What documents will I need from my friend/her husband, if I opt for this route for the proof of accommodation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of accommodation is usually required for entry. You can get a copy of letter similar to this and it will be considered a valid proof of accommodation (I used same format many times for my friends visiting me).

Present this letter only if you are asked to present a proof.

```
To, Immigration Officer, UAE

This is to confirm the invitation of my friend,
<Your Name> ( Indian passport number XXXX of address,
<< YOUR ADDRESS in Passport >>>
to spend a few days with me at my home address
between the dates xxx and xxx.
I am attaching a copy of my UAE employment pass issued
to my passport (number : xxxxxxxxxx)
and a past copy of xxxxx as address proof.
I undertake to ensure that <Your name> terms of their visa
and exits UAE accordingly.

<Attach copy of the above mentioned documents>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Just out of curiosity, did your friends visit you in the UAE?

Comment: @trollster No. I used it for Singapore and Malaysia. But this is universal and perfectly applicable as a replacement for Hotel Accomodation.

Although, for transit, its rarely asked. So, show only if asked.